# Как отсортировать посты, которые лайкнул пользователь в DJANGO?

Tags: python, django

Есть модель **Post**:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField("Text", blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to="post_img", blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="post_like")
```

И мне нужно отсортировать в **ListView** посты так, чтобы были только те которые **лайкнул пользователь**.
Пытаюсь делать так, но не получается.

```py
class PostUrLikes(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'post_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Post.objects.filter(user in F('likes'))
```

Помогите

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели сказать - отфильтровать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделать довольно просто, у тебя связь ManyToMany, поэтому ты сможешь с помощью `related_name` которую указал в модели обратиться через User объект.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, 
        blank=True,
        related_name="post_like" # вот тут
    )

class PostUrLikes(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    ... 
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        # Помимо .all() можно и другие ORM фишки использовать, 
        # например filter(), order_by(), count() итд...
        return user.post_like.all()
```